# How to find null documents in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I'm a complete beginner in mongodb . Actually I'm trying to find all the documents containing null or nothing  for example documents like `{
    "_id" : "abc"
}` for deleting them from collection.

But even after searching a lot of `SO` questions I couldn't get any solution .So, how can I do this ? and sorry if I'm ignoring anything.

Comment: Do you know the names of the possible attributes other than `_id`?

Comment: No I know only the name of _id by assigning a custom name to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to do it in a single operation, but you can try something like this:

```
db["collectionName"].find({_id: {$exists: true}}).forEach(function(doc) {
  if (Object.keys(doc).length === 1) {
    // ..delete this document db["collectionName"].remove({_id: doc._id})
  }
})
```

Comment: No nothing is happening by this

Comment: Did you try to execute only the query: `db["collectionName"].find({_id: {$exists: true}})`? Does it return something?

Comment: Sir, it's returning all the documents

Comment: Correct...so if you apply the `forEach` function, you can delete the doc that contains only the `_id`. Uncomment the remove part.

Comment: Exactly I tried your solution even I tried to print the _id but it's not printing anything   db.collection("messaging_relation").find({_id: {$exists: true}}).forEach(function(doc) {
           
            if (Object.keys(doc).lenght === 1) {
                // ..delete this document db["collectionName"].remove({_id: doc._id})
                console.log(doc._id)
              }
            
        })

Comment: Ops...probably there was a typo in `length`. Try now.

Comment: thanks a lot sir, it's the simplest yet best solution

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to get a list of the `_id` values of those null field documents and then remove them. This can be significantly efficient considering that you only execute two queries instead of looping through the whole collection (this can potentially affect your db performance especially with large collections).

Consider running the following aggregate pipeline to get those ids:

```
var ids = db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "hashmaps": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" } 
    } }, 
    { "$project": {
        "keys": "$hashmaps.k"
    } },
    { "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                {
                    "$eq":[
                        {
                            "$ifNull": [
                                { "$arrayElemAt": ["$keys", 1] },
                                0
                            ]
                        },
                        0
                    ]
                },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
    } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "ids": { "$push": "$_id" }
    } }
]).toArray()[0]["ids"];
```

Removing the documents

```
db.collection.remove({ "_id": { "$in": ids } });
```

---

The other approach is similar to the above in that you would need two queries; the first which returns a list of all the top level fields in the collection and the last removes the documents from the collection which do not have those fields altogether.

Consider running the following queries:

```
/* 
   Run an aggregate pipeline operation to get a list 
   of all the top-level fields in the collection
*/
var fields = db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
       "hashmaps": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" } 
    } }, 
    { "$project": {
       "keys": "$hashmaps.k"
    } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "fields": { "$addToSet": "$keys" }
    } },
    { "$project": {
            "fields": {
                "$setDifference": [
                    {
                        "$reduce": {
                            "input": "$fields",
                            "initialValue": [],
                            "in": { "$setUnion" : ["$$value", "$$this"] }
                        }
                    },
                    ["_id"]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]).toArray()[0]["fields"];
```

The second query looks for the existence of all the fields except the `_id` one. For example, suppose your collection has documents with the keys `_id`, `a`, `b` and `c`, the query

```
db.collection.find({ 
    "a" : { "$exists": false },
    "b" : { "$exists": false },
    "c" : { "$exists": false }
});
```

matches documents that do not contain the all the three fields **a**, **b** AND **c**:

So if you have a list of the top level fields in your collection then all you need is to construct the above query document. Use reduce method on the array for this:

```
// Construct the above query
var query = fields.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
    acc[curr] = { "$exists": false };
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Then use the query to remove the documents as

```
db.collection.remove(query);
```