# How to find the count of documents containing null values in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb

I have gone thorough the stackoverflow link **[How to find null documents in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48977828/how-to-find-null-documents-in-mongodb)** , but it returns all documents and not just Null. Also, I just need the count and no actions on the Null-containing Documents.

So, the background is, I've imported the collection from MongoDB 4.0.17 to AWS DocumentDB (~Mongo 3.6). I see that are 2000 documents less in the new DocumentDB. Also below is the error message that i received during the restore/import.

```
2020-04-15T12:31:07.412+0000    [####################....]  prod.original_post  1.65GB/1.96GB  (84.3%)
2020-04-15T12:31:08.347+0000    error: Unsupported BSON : has null character in string
2020-04-15T12:31:10.412+0000    [####################....]  prod.original_post  1.68GB/1.96GB  (85.8%)
2020-04-15T12:31:22.417+0000    [######################..]  prod.original_post  1.81GB/1.96GB  (92.1%)
2020-04-15T12:31:31.602+0000    [########################]  prod.original_post  1.96GB/1.96GB  (100.0%)
2020-04-15T12:31:31.602+0000    restoring indexes for collection prod.original_post from metadata
2020-04-15T12:32:11.687+0000    finished restoring prod.original_post (3700504 documents)
2020-04-15T12:32:11.687+0000    done
```

And, following the AWS forum https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=908846 I tried to make sure that the missing documents are due to the Null Values. But unable to take a Null-valued documents' count.

Comment: `Unsupported BSON : has null character in string` -> Is that for a string field ?

Comment: @whoami Yeah looks like that. but there are many string fields in a document.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things -

- Amazon DocumentDB does not allow the null character (Unicode \u0000) in string value. That is likely the reason you see 2000 records less in your DocumentDB cluster. The DocumentDB team is however working on adding support for null characters.

In the meanwhile, as suggested in the AWS forum, there are two ways to mitigate this:

- Search your source MongoDB collections for strings with a null character, and replace the null character with space/other character/nothing as is appropriate for your use case.
- For CDC migration, use the appropriate DMS Error Handling Task Setting (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TaskSettings.ErrorHandling.html) to log the error and continue, then review the errors and edit/migrate those documents separately.

On how to identify which documents have null values, using Oled's approach makes sense to me.

Comment: Amazon DocumentDB now supports null characters. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/06/amazon-documentdb-with-mongodb-compatibility-adds-new-capabilities/

Answer (score 0):

> I see that are 2000 documents less in the new DocumentDB.

To locate the missing documents:

1. Retrieve _ids of all the documents that are in DocumentDB.
2. Retrieve _ids of all the documents that are in MongoDB.
3. Subtract set 1 from set 2.
4. Fetch documents from MongoDB with _id in set 3.

Comment: Logic seems to be fine. but anything less resource intensive? the command to find all objects id fails for me with the error "Assertion failure: [unhandlable oom] Failed to allocate object while tenuring."

Comment: I am not familiar with that error but generally both the database and the driver are capable of streaming arbitrary result sets to the application, and since you're only retrieving ids you shouldn't need that much memory in the application either.